# Fraction bar not showing with custom math font

Tags: fractions, line

I'm using unicode-math package to change my math font. Initially the fractions weren't rentering correctly but now I've got almost everything to look good with some adjustments using \fontdimen but the fraction bar won't show.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{MyMathFont.otf}[Path=./fonts/mathfont/]

\makeatletter
 \AtBeginDocument{
   \setbox0=\hbox{
    \check@mathfonts{
      \fontdimen8\textfont2=8pt       % shift standard size numerator up by this amount
      \fontdimen10\textfont2=3.5pt      % alternative numerator shift
      \fontdimen11\textfont2=8pt      % shift standard size denominator down by this amount
      \fontdimen12\textfont2=3.5pt      % alternative denominator shift
      }
     }
    }

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    1 - \frac{\pi ^ 2}{\exp(\tau)} x ^ 2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This renders the following:

[image]

Is there a way to force the bar? Is there something wrong with my font in the first place?

If I don't use any of the `\fontdimen` commands it ends up looking like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the opentype math layout doesn't use the classic tex numbered font parameters, it uses the named parameters that luatex extracts from the Opentype Math table in the font, does your font have a MATH table?

Comment: Yes, it comes with a couple of files and it says its specifically designed to be implemeted in LaTeX. However I don't know how to implement something like that in Overleaf.

Comment: sorry that doesn't actually answer the question what "couple of files"? Do you get any warnings or errors from unicode-math showing the log would be more useful than showing the output if there were errors

Comment: No erros or warnings when compiling. A couple of files is perhaps too ambiguous, I have files with the following extensions: .map .pl .tfm .vf .fd .sty. Might also be worth mentioning that I use XeLaTeX to use unicode-math. I looked in the logs and I am getting the following which might be interesting:
`\inf@bad=\count270

LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.

\uproot@=\count271`

Comment: If changing these fontdimens had any effect in XeTeX than the font does not contain a MATH table. Such fonts are not compatible with `unicode-math`. Maybe you should try to use the other files instead to load the font as a traditional TeX math font.

Comment: actually for xetex the rule thickness is fontdimen48 (FractionRuleThickness) but as Marcel says the suspicion is that the font is not an Openype Math font,

Comment: If you have tfm metrics for your math font then it is not for use with unicode-math package which is explicitly not for tfm fonts bu for Unicode (OpenType) math fonts.

Comment: I tried changing dimension 48, in that case I get an error saying the font only has 22 dimensions. I might attempt to load the font using LaTeX and some more traditioal method instead then, or find a similar OpenType font that's ready to use.